# Disconnect bluetooth device with script (mac os x)

Tags: bash, macos, bluetooth, applescript

I'm looking for a way to disconnect a bluetooth device on a Mac with a script (can be apple script, bash cmd, python, etc). Anything that can be added to other scripts.

**I don't want to shut off bluetooth**, just the selected device.

For the moment, I'm doing it manually using top right command bar -> bluetooth -> device -> XXX -> disconnect.

I tried (thanks to @Janek comment) this script :

```
set btDevice to "Smart Reader 2501"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer"
    set bt to (first menu bar item whose description is "bluetooth") of menu bar 1
    click bt
    tell (first menu item whose title is btDevice) of menu of bt
        click
        tell menu 1
            if exists menu item "Disconnect" then
                click menu item "Disconnect"
            else if exists menu item "Déconnecter" then
                click menu item "Déconnecter"
            else
                click bt -- close main dropdown to clean up after ourselves
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But I see three problems in this approach :

- It's language dependent (so I need two line by language)
- We see all actions (so It's not very conviennent for the user)
- Most important : The device connects back after disconnection

For the last one, a it might be related to bluetooth device pairing handling, I suspect that I will never be able to disconnect it.

But If you have any other clue, I take it !

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps this thread might help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8343/is-it-possible-to-disconnect-a-bluetooth-connection-using-applescript

Comment: Thanks @Janek I tried that and it worked (even if we see all clicking actions and it's not very convenient). But more important, after disconnection, the device connects-back immediately. But I'm pretty sure that this is due to bluetooth connection and we cannot manage to really disconnect the device. I update my question with that.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/352843/358510 Worked well for me